# Subscribing and unsubscribing to an event when the method is sometimes passed a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, events, blazor-webassembly

I have a service and component that work together in Blazor to load my user settings when the app loads. The service looks like this:

```
public class AppSettingsService
    {
        private HttpClient _client { get; }

        public AppSettingsService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<UserSettingDto> GetUserSettings()
        {
            return await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<UserSettingDto>($"api/General/Settings/GetUserSettings/");
        }

        public async Task<UserSettingDto> ClearAndGetUserSettings(int? aliasUserId = null)
        {
            return await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<UserSettingDto>($"api/General/Settings/ClearAndGetUserSettings/{aliasUserId}");
        }

        public void UpdateUserSettings(int? aliasUserId = null)
        {
            OnUserSettingsChanged();
        }

        private void OnUserSettingsChanged() => UserSettingsChanged?.Invoke();

        public event Func<Task>? UserSettingsChanged;
    }
```

The code for the component (AppSettingsComponent) looks like this:

```
@inject AppSettingsService AppSettingsService
@implements IDisposable

@if (schoolSettings == null || userSettings == null)
{
    <p>Loading Settings...</p>
}
else
{
    <CascadingValue Value="@schoolSettings" IsFixed="false">
        <CascadingValue Value="@userSettings" IsFixed="false">
            @ChildContent
        </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>
}

@code {
    private UserSettingDto userSettings = new UserSettingDto();

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Inject] AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppSettingsService.UserSettingsChanged += UpdateUserSettings;

        var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userSettings = await AppSettingsService.GetUserSettings();
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateUserSettings(int? aliasUserId = null)
    {
        userSettings = await AppSettingsService.ClearAndGetUserSettings(aliasUserId);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppSettingsService.UserSettingsChanged -= UpdateUserSettings;
    }
}
```

At the moment it's throwing an error because I realised that I sometimes need to be able to pass an `aliasUserId` through to my `UpdateUserSettings` method so that I could build in a feature for logging in as other users.

The error I'm getting is in my AppSettingsComponent where I'm trying to subscribe and unsubscribe `UpdateUserSettings` to the `UserSettingsChanged` event.

The error is:

No overload for 'UpdateUserSettings' matches delegate 'Func'

Unfortunately my knowledge of handling events in C# is not very good and I'm not even sure what I need to search for to figure this out! Is Func even the right type of event to be using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is declared as

```cs
public event Func<Task>? UserSettingsChanged;
```

This means that a method with this signature is expected: `Task Method()`, but the method you are trying to register has the signature `Task Method(int? arg)` which corrsponds to `Func<int?, Task>`.

Change the event declaration and `On..` method to

```cs
private void OnUserSettingsChanged(int? aliasUserId = null) => 
    UserSettingsChanged?.Invoke(aliasUserId);

public event Func<int?,Task>? UserSettingsChanged;
```

---

Another possibility is to keep the event as is and to register the method with:

```cs
AppSettingsService.UserSettingsChanged += () => UpdateUserSettings();
```

Where `null` will be passed as an argument to the optional parameter.